# EmberJS: stuck with initial routing, controllers and templates with v1.11.0 (noobie)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to EmberJS, I set up a simple project using ember-cli and I have the following code in my app:
**routes/person.js**

```
 import Ember from "ember";
 export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, person) {
    controller.set('model', person);
  },

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('person', 1); // returns a promise that will resolve
  },
});
```

**models/person.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

let Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    birthDate: DS.attr('string'),
});

Person.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Jack Sparrow', birthDate: 'Glowacki' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Long John Silver' , birthDate: 'Dale'     }
  ]
});

export default Person;
```

**controllers/person.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    findPerson: function(){
        //do a HTTP call to the mzalendo API
    },

});
```

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
      this.route('person', { path: '/person' });

});
```

**templates/person.hbs**

```
<strong>Name: {{name}} </strong>
```

When I run the server and go to http://localhost:4200/persons nothing loads and there's no error, am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

Fired up the JS console and saw this error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/people 404 (Not Found)jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.js:9659jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9210ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax @ rest-adapter.js:792initializePromise @ ember.debug.js:46984Promise @ ember.debug.js:48612ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax @ rest-adapter.js:776ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.findAll @ rest-adapter.js:371ember$data$lib$system$store$finders$$_findAll @ finders.js:115ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._fetchAll @ store.js:997ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.fetchAll @ store.js:570ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.findAll @ store.js:978ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.find @ store.js:514model @ persons.js:7EmberObject.default.extend.deserialize @ ember.debug.js:22623applyHook @ ember.debug.js:46611HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook @ ember.debug.js:44612subclass.getModel @ ember.debug.js:44838__exports__.bind @ ember.debug.js:46480tryCatch @ ember.debug.js:46937invokeCallback @ ember.debug.js:46949publish @ ember.debug.js:46920(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:27239Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:871Queue.flush @ ember.debug.js:936DeferredActionQueues.flush @ ember.debug.js:741Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:166Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:221Backburner.join @ ember.debug.js:240run.join @ ember.debug.js:15966run.bind @ ember.debug.js:16021jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.js:3143jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.js:3255jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3467completed @ jquery.js:3498
ember.debug.js:24085 Error while processing route: persons Not Found Error: Not Found
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajaxError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:62085:35)
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax.Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:62160:45)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3345:30)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3457:7)
    at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9513:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9915:8)
```

Not sure where the **/people** route is coming from

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue, you need to [set the application adapter](http://www.ember-cli.com/#mocks-and-fixtures) to `FixtureAdapter`:

```
$ ember g adapter application
```

then

```
// adapters/application.js
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

**EDIT**

you'll also need to load the records in your persons route:

```
$ ember g route persons
```

then:

```
//routes/persons.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('person');
  }
});
```

As far as I can tell, it's because FixtureAdapter doesn't set up smart defaults for you like the RESTAdapter does.

**EDIT 2:**

Ember has an inflector. So to Ember, the plural of person is people, which you can see in your browser console `Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize('person') //=> "people"`

so just rename `routes/persons.js` to `routes/people.js` and visit **/people**.

P.S. you shouldn't need that `setupController`. Your `model` hook already does that.

Comment: Added adapter and removed the setUpController, still nothing loads, an error would help me figure out what is going on..